# Unable to deploy application in Rhino

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rhino, telecommunication

When I try to deploy my application in rhino server, I always get below exception

```
     javax.sip.SipException: error starting stack
        at com.opencloud.ob.ocsipra.fY.a(2.3.1.15:69)
        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)

        failed to activate RA entity, check RA entity configuration
        Cause: javax.sip.SipException: error starting stack
        at com.opencloud.ob.ocsipra.fY.a(2.3.1.15:69)

        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

Below is output of netstat command,

```
netstat -aon | findstr 5060
```

TCP    0.0.0.0:5060           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1336
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5060           *:*                                    1336

```
 netstat -aon | findstr 5061
```

TCP    10.111.115.147:58236   10.55.202.82:5061      ESTABLISHED     6364

netstat -aon | findstr 5062

Answer (score 0):

As I was finding processes using **netstat -aon** command it always use to give process names as TCP and UDP but using **resmon.exe** in Run u can see resource monitor where you can see which software is using that port. I could resolve this by the same.